# TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, jupyter

Dispongo del siguiente dataframe con un índice único.

```
#Media cuadrática de los números 
tabla = {'LimitesExactos' : ["0-5", "5-10", "10-15", "15-20", "20-25", "25-30"],
         "Li": [0, 5, 10, 15, 20, 25], "Ls" : [5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30], 
         "fi": [6, 10, 3, 5, 9, 4], "Fi": [6, 16, 19, 24, 33, 37]}
tabla = pd.DataFrame(tabla, dtype = np.float64)
sumafi = tabla["fi"]
print (tabla, "\n")
```

Con la sentencia

```
Mo = tabla["fi"].max()
```

Obtengo el valor máximo de la columna "fi".
Necesito ahora saber en qué fila del dataframe se encuentra dicho valor.
La sentencia

```
df.loc[tabla["fi"].idxmax()]
```

me devuelve el error

```
TypeError: 'numpy.float64' object is not callable
```

A qué se debe este error?. ¿Existe lguna otra manera mejor de obtener el resultado deseado?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

He encontrado esta solución.

```
tabla["fi"].idxmax(skipna = True)
```

El numpy error se debía al df. La sentencia correcta sería.
El error estaba en el df. La sentencia queda  `tabla["fi"].loc[tabla["fi"].idxmax(axis = 0)]`

Comment: El error estaba en el df. La sentencia queda

Comment: recuerda aceptar tu respuesta para que comunidad no la vuelva a *revivir*